# Scala formatted tuple string to Tuple

Tags: scala

I am trying to change a string of a tuple to a tuple.

For example, given a string:

```
val str: String = "(some string, somestring, null)"
```

How can I convert it to a Tuple. E.g:

```
val tup: Tuple3 = ("some string", "somestring", null)
```

Comment: what's the result type of tuples: is this only strings or other objects?

Comment: Only strings and nulls. No other type

Comment: There will be always three elements?

Comment: In this case yes, always three elements thus the Tuple3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. On of them is:

```
val str: String = "(some string, somestring, null)"
val result = str match {
  case s"($a, $b, $c)" => (a, b, c)
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CX50gTlXTjWFIMOvVXBeMA).

As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez mentioned in the comment (and I missed originally, thanks Luis!), you want to convert the string `null` into `null`. Before actually doing that, I'd recommend reading:

- [NO NULL VALUES](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/no-null-values.html) in Scala book.
- [Scala best practice: Eliminate null values from your code](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/best-practice-eliminate-null-values-from-code-scala-idioms/) By Alvin Alexander.

If you decided to use `null` after all, you can do:

```
def ifNullStringReturNull(s: String): String = if (s == "null") null else s
val str: String = "(some string, somestring, null)"
val result = str match {
  case s"($a, $b, $c)" => (ifNullStringReturNull(a), ifNullStringReturNull(b), ifNullStringReturNull(c))
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/T6D2j1HqQvuDxn99MkwSmQ).

Comment: @TomerShetah: Of course, the fact that `null` is a valid everything is that we're not using it in the first place :-D